# How to ungroup native crash reports in Fabric?

Tags: android, c++, crashlytics, google-fabric

We use Crashlytics for reporting crashes faced by our Android app users. A lot of our code is native (c++), hence a lot of crashes are in native code. However most (if not all) of them end up getting grouped under **"abort_message.cpp line 77"**. And this is the top part of the stacktrace for all kind of different crashes -
[image: crashlytics native crash stack]

I have tested by making different kinds of crashes in different files, like `throw std::runtime_error("Testing crash")`, `throw std::logic_error("Testing crash2")`, but all of them end up having the top few frames same (as the image above).

Now since the top frame of crash stack is `abort_message.cpp line 77` for all of them, they get grouped under same head.

Grouping dissimilar crashes in same group, makes it hard to prioritize and target crash fixes. So is there anyway we can fix this? Or workaround this?

NOTE: We are uploading native symbols to crashlytics alright, and our stack traces are quite detailed.

Another thing that bothers me is that different type of crashes are all reported as SIGABRT.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

This looks to be a C++ exception that Crashlytics is not unwinding very well - this is an aspect of NDK integration with Crashlytics that we're looking to improve for the future. When a C++ exception is thrown, the signal that is raised by an uncaught C++ exception is processed rather than handling the exception itself, resulting in these first few frames of the stacktrace being the same and grouping together different issues as a result.

It should still have the relevant crash information, so the frames below should be different, but the blame frame will be that *abort_message* frame.

Thanks for the report - it's definitely something we're looking into making better soon.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for confirming this. I thought the same. And looking forward to improvements around this issue in Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same complaint.
Is there a workaround?
Just received a spike alert from Firebase from having the same error spiking, and they were all unrelated crashes (from throw exceptions incorrectly grouped as the same)